# Using a super-cap with a PIC24F to keep time in case of supply failure

Tags: capacitor

I want to use a 0.1F 5.5V supercap to keep time with a PIC24FJ64GA004 device. Does anyone have any idea on how to implement this?

I was thinking of using the supercap on the +3.3V supply line and monitoring the battery input. When the main supply drops below say 5V I would put the micro into ultra low power sleep mode (~400-500nA with RTCC.)

Does anyone know how long a 0.1F cap lasts with <1µA current draw? It'll be charged up to 3.3V and 2.0V is the terminal voltage, though it would probably work down even lower.

Comment: A suoercap has a significant self-discharge that is in the same order of magnitude as your load.

Comment: So any idea how long it will go even with that discharge? If it went for a few weeks it would probably be okay. Otherwise, I may need a supply monitor IC and a coin cell.

Comment: I would use a coin cell.

Comment: seconded. A coin cell just gets the job done.

Comment: As a side note, Super-caps are actually starting to be used on computer motherboards and GPSs. In any typical motherboard you wont loose power for too long and it doesn't take much power to keep a realtime clock. GPSs uses it to keep the last known gps position to get a faster lock on turn on.

Comment: 36 Hours Ref: http://www.maxim-ic.com/tools/calculators/index.cfm/calc_id/supercap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to page 4 this [document](http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ABC0000/ABC0000TE5.pdf), a 0.047F 5.5V supercap will drop from 3.3v to 2.0v in about 18 hours with a 3.75M load (<1µA).  So I would expect your 0.1F cap to do about twice that.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'm going to have to use a coin cell instead. :( I could use a 1F cap, but they get bigger and bigger...

Answer (score 1):

I've used a super-cap to power an external real-time clock before. The super-cap works quite well and it will power a DS1306 for almost two weeks.

I've never tried implementing a super-cap backed up real-time clock implemented using a PIC24. The problem is how will you isolate the super-cap from the rest of your circuit when you lose primary power? If you just connect the super-cap between your primary power and ground when you lose power the super-cap will be trying to supply power to the whole circuit and it will drain it very quickly.

Comment: what size supercap did you use?

Comment: I used a 0.47F super-cap.

Comment: How much current does the DS1306 draw in its standby mode? I couldn't find that parameter in its datasheet.

Comment: Between 0.4uA and 1.0uA depending on VCC.